# WebApi auth using Azure AD

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I've integrated Azure AD within Umbraco v8 using this [blog post](https://shazwazza.com/post/configuring-azure-active-directory-login-with-umbraco/) which works perfectly. The issue now is that WebApis are not working as the external login (AD) kicks in even when including the Authorization header with the WebApis call

I get the below redirect when doing a normal WebApi call.
[image: WebApi call image]

So my question is, how would I make AD authenticates my WebApi calls using the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting a local account (username and password). The issue was that the user I tried authenticating with had no Content and Media start nodes, so Umbraco falls back to Azure AD authentication. Once set all is good.